# Segmentation fault when run as root?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, maemo

My c++ program gives me a seg fault when I run as root from my computer but not when I start a remote session. My program run from my computer only as a user. What can be the problem? I wrote my program for an embedded device and I'm using this to compile:

```
gcc -Werror notify.cc -o notify `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 hildon-notifymm hildonmm hildon-fmmm'
```

I'm not getting any error. Could it be a flag problem? I can post my code.

EDIT: When I start my program with gdb I get this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x40eed060 in strcmp () from /lib/libc.so.6
0x40eed060 <strcmp+0>:  ldrb    r2, [r0], #1
```

Backtrace give this:

```
(gdb) backtrace
 #0  0x40eed060 in strcmp () from /lib/libc.so.6
 #1  0x40b7f190 in dbus_set_g_error ()
 from /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2
 #2  0x40b7d060 in dbus_g_bus_get () from /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2
 #3  0x400558ec in notify_init () from /usr/lib/libnotify.so.1
 #4  0x4004a240 in Notify::init(Glib::ustring const&) ()
 from /usr/lib/libnotifymm-1.0.so.7
 #5  0x40033794 in Hildon::notify_init(Glib::ustring const&) ()
 from /usr/lib/libhildon-notifymm-1.0.so.1
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <hildonmm.h>
#include <hildon-notifymm.h>
#include <hildon/hildon-notification.h>
#include <libnotifymm/init.h>
#include <gtkmm/stock.h>
#include <dbus/dbus.h>
#include <dbus/dbus-glib.h>
#include <dbus/dbus-glib-lowlevel.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Initialize gtkmm and maemomm:

Hildon::init();
Hildon::notify_init("Notification Example");

// Initialize D-Bus (needed by hildon-notify):
DBusConnection* conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, NULL);
dbus_connection_setup_with_g_main(conn, NULL);

// Create a new notification:
Glib::RefPtr<Hildon::Notification> notification =   Hildon::Notification::create("Something Happened", "A thing has just happened.", Gtk::Stock::OPEN);

// Show the notification:
std::auto_ptr<Glib::Error> ex;
notification->show(ex);
if(ex.get())
{ 
std::cerr << "Notification::show() failed: " << ex->what() << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Problem solved. Program needs a DBUS_SESSION_ADDRESS in the env of the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to run your program under `valgrind`. I wrote a tiny program that writes outside of an allocated array:

```
$ valgrind ./segfault
==11830== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11830== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11830== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11830== Command: ./segfault
==11830== 
==11830== Invalid write of size 1
==11830==    at 0x4004BF: main (in /tmp/segfault)
==11830==  Address 0x7feff65bf is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==11830== 
==11830== 
==11830== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==11830==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FEFF65BF
==11830==    at 0x4004BF: main (in /tmp/segfault)
==11830==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==11830==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==11830==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==11830==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==11830==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==11830== 
==11830== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11830==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11830==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==11830== 
==11830== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11830== 
==11830== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11830== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
Segmentation fault
```

The most important part of this output is here:

```
==11830== Invalid write of size 1
==11830==    at 0x4004BF: main (in /tmp/segfault)
```

The `write of size 1` might help you figure out which line was involved:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char f[1];
    f[-40000]='c';
    return 0;
}
```

Another very useful tool to know is `gdb`. If you set your rlimits to allow dumping core (see `setrlimit(2)` for details on the limits, and your shell's manual (probably `bash(1)`) for details on the `ulimit` built-in command) then you can get a core file for use with `gdb`:

```
$ ulimit -c 1000
$ ./segfault 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ gdb --core=core ./segfault
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /tmp/segfault...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New Thread 11951]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
Reading symbols from /lib/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/libc-2.12.1.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/ld-2.12.1.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Core was generated by `./segfault'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004004bf in main ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004004bf in main ()
(gdb) quit
```

Depending upon the size of your program, you might need to give way more than `1000` blocks to the allowed core file. If this program were remotely complicated, knowing the call chain to get to the segfault could be vital information.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you've invoked undefined behavior somewhere. Undefined behavior can behave differently on different machines, different runs on the same machine, whatever. You've got to find where you let a wild pointer happen and deal with it.

Most likely you're just getting "lucky" when running as a limited user and either the page permissions on your process are set to allow whatever invalid memory access you're getting, or you have some root-specific code which isn't being reached when run in usermode only.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say anything specific without seeing any code, so I'll give you some general
advice:  learn to use your debugger (probably gdb), and try to reproduce the failure
under the debugger.  If you're lucky, the segfault will still occur under the debugger,
you'll get a stack trace showing where it failed, and that will give you a starting point that will let you work your way back to the true source of the problem.

If you're unlucky, the problem might disappear if you compile with debugging support, or 
run it under gdb. In that case you'll have to resort to code inspection, and scrub your 
code for any undefined behavior (for example, wild or uninitialized pointers, as 
Billy ONeal suggests).

Answer (score 2):

Set `ulimit -c unlimited`.

Run your program and let it crash. It should now core dump.

Run `gdb <program-name> core`

If you use the `bt` (backtrace) command, it should give you a good idea where the crash is happening. This should then help you fix it.