# How to minimize program startup time

Tags: c, linux, performance, raspberry-pi

I have written a simple tool in C using codeblocks for Raspberry Pi that executes commands over SPI bus. Codeblocks uses GCC compiler. 
The problem is that while the actual SPI transaction takes single digit milliseconds, total program execution can be 100ms or more. Actual program execution inside the code does not take long either so it's presumably all consumed by setting up the process etc.

What would be good approaches to minimize the startup delay here? Raspberry pi is hardly a speed daemon and the program needs to be executed with root privileges that the SPI library requires. The executable is around 70kB so at the glacial RPI Sdcard interface (around 6MB/s for 4kB block reads) it would take roughly 12ms to load the executable alone. I could always create a small ramdisk for it I guess.

Sudo alone takes around 50ms to execute so actually starting a root session shaves execution time to 30-40ms. Is there any way to make sudo happen faster so I don't have to have root console open for this..?

Comment: I guess that the usual approach to excessive startup time is to not continually start up the app, ie. run it as a daemon/service, (well, most of it anyway).

Comment: How much time does it take for a trivial "hello world\n" program to start and run? (BTW: you don't need a ramdisk. After the first run, the program will probably be fetched from the buffer cache) `there any way to make sudo happen faste` I think sudo is the time-consuming part here.

Comment: @joop As I pointed out, running this from root shell shaves off around 50ms. Setting SUID bit does the same thing in fact.

Comment: @MartinJames Now if only I knew how to write such a thing. A bit overkill for a simple tool but since I need to be able to do 120 transactions a second .. I could always pass it off as an example code but I suspect it'll be back on my desk when the client figures out they cannot achieve required speed.

Comment: Looks like writing a daemon isn't really that hard, but it introduces a catch-22 situation - I then need another program to feed the daemon the commands that I want to execute along with binary data to be transferred. And presumably that program again will take tens of milliseconds to execute.

Comment: BTW: if you use spidev, you can avoid setuid root, by allowing a group or user rw access to the /dev/spidevXXX device node. (you'd still have to handle the input/output conversion in your progam) Another way would be to use a named pipe or (unix-domain) socket for a daemon program. (which would need the same amount of conversion/data formatting)

Comment: @joop I'm actually using BCM2835 library. Wiring pi could also do it but the documentation isn't as good. I haven't actually tried using spidev directly, googling rpi spi bus tends to take you to those two libraries. Hello world alone takes 9ms to execute, even if you remove print. I wonder would reliable "time" actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `sudo` I would think that a good start would be to set SUID bit.

With this bit and ownership of your binary set to `root` you can allow a regular user to run your file without referring to `sudo`.

```
chown root:root your_binary
chmod u+s your_binary
```

Of course you should be aware of all the possible dangers of using SUID, especially if you accept user input or parameters in your application. This is the first hit I found: http://unix.worldiswelcome.com/why-suid-programs-are-dangerous

On the other hand, SUID is not **bad**. Just like `goto` is not bad. It can be used in a bad way, but the mechanism is there and it may solve your problem.

**EDIT**: Second idea - do you link dynamically against many libraries? This, as far as I know, may introduce some delays. Maybe you can aim for static linking? But, honestly speaking, I think you may also loose performance because of poor memory/cache usage, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yup, that does get sudo out of the equation. On the other hand the utility now segfaults on exit for some reason.. The same thing happens if you run it from root shell actually. With sudo there's no problem.

Comment: Just as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233656/segmentation-fault-when-run-as-root - there are many reasons, it's difficult to say anything without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Good stuff. I mostly write embedded C where you don't have any of these nice system level tools. If you go out of bounds or something it's blood, sweat and tears to figure out where. It's interesting that with sudo it does not crash, with SUID it does. BTW it crashes at exit after successfully doing all of it's stuff.

Comment: The first thing I would try is `ulimit -c unlimited`, so that your app creates a core dump to analyze in GDB. From my personal experience it's the best way to find the problem. And I know your pain in embedded, same industry here :) You won't get a segfault if there is no memory management...

Comment: Added a hint about shared libraries

Comment: I was just missing an exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); at the end.